# sequence of discrete random variables - exchange expectation and countable summation

Tags: probability, probability-limit-theorems

For a sequence of non-negative random variables $(X_n)_{n\geq1}$ holds
$$\mathbb E\left[\sum_{n\geq 1}X_n\right]=\sum_{n\geq 1}\mathbb E[X_n].$$

Is this because one can define an increasing sequence of r.v.s $Y_n:=\sum_{k=1}^nX_k$? What would be the argument, if i do not know, whether the sequece of $X_n$ converges or not?

Answer (score 2):

The sequence $ Y_n$ as you defined it increases monotonously to $ Y := \sum_{n=1}^\infty X_n $, hence by the [monotone convergence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_convergence_theorem#Beppo_Levi%27s_lemma) (MCT), $$ \mathbb{E}[Y] = \mathbb{E}[\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} Y_n] \overset{\text{MCT}}{=} \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \mathbb{E}[Y_n] = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \mathbb{E}[X_n]. $$

Some details:

- The MCT is applied to integration against the underlying probability measure $\mathbb{P}$ using that $\mathbb{E}[X] = \int X \mathrm{d}\mathbb{P}$ by definition.
- Convergence of $ Y_n $ to $Y$ is in the sense that we   admit for the possibility that $ Y_n(\omega) \rightarrow \infty $ for some $ \omega \in \Omega$ (the underlying probability space). In this case, $Y(\omega) = \infty$, which is poses no obstacle for the MCT.

Comment: Thanks! I was actually asking this, because in my book (Ethier, Doctrine of Chances, p.748) this result is stated before the MCT.

Comment: Ah, I see! I'm unaware how this would be proven without the MCT.